# Can we use scenario outline for background steps

Tags: background, cucumber

I am using POM with cucumber. I have 3 scenarios to execute where half of the steps are common for all the scenarios. So I am using background keyword for common steps. But I need to pass data through Example keyword to the steps defined in Background as well. How do I do it?

Below is my background

```
Given User is on login Screen
When user enters "<User_ID>" and "<Password>"
Then verify successfull login
When user clicks on search button 
And search by "<reference_number>"

Examples:
| User_ID | Password |reference number |
| Abc     | XYZ      |ABC123 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to pass example data from a scenario outline to the background. You will need to include those parameterized steps in the scenario outline rather than the background. If one step depends on another, they are probably stuck repeating steps in each scenario.

Comment: but those steps which are in background are common steps and I don't want to repeat the steps.So.is there any alternative?

Comment: @MangalaHegde: Can you add the background and one of the scenario outlines to your question? Maybe seeing what you already have will help us answer your question.

Comment: Background: 

Given User is on login Screen and selects the client
When user enters "<User_ID>" and "<Password>"
| User_ID | Password |
| Abc| Abc.  |
Then verify successfull login
When user clicks on search button 
And search by "<reference_number>"
|reference number |
|XYZ |
Then user clicks on

Comment: @MangalaHegde: Please add that to your question. Reading code in comments is nearly impossible.